Old concrete floor in garage. Animals digging in the holes
I have an old concrete garage slab.  There are several cracks in the floor, along with a few open holes.  It appears critter(s) are getting in one of the holes and burrowing, evidenced by sand being dug up next to the hole.  Replacing the entire garage floor slab is not an option at this time. How can I fill the hole, as to not have my concrete sink because of the burrowing?

What are the size of the holes?

It is probably ants.  Either get a commercial bait for insects that you can place around the hole.  Or, just drown them with your choice of liquid (pour it until it overflows and keep repeating).

Just Water
Water with lots of detergent
Vegetable Oil
Insecticide


The burrowing is unlikely to sink the concrete. Having said that, depending on the size of the holes, you have several options:
-- get a sac of mortar mix, add water, mix and spread. This the cheapest and best option, but it's a mess to do and might be too much product for your needs
-- buy a small amount of mortar substitute that comes ready to apply. This will quickly get too expensive if you need more than a liter.
-- get a tube of siliconized landscape glue/filler.
